# Highcharts load data from server ok, but not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I load succesfully from database but then it doesn't update dynamic. The function `InitHighchart` produce Highchart and I am trying to update series using requestData function

```
function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://....url.../json.php',
            data: {region:region},   
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',

            error: function (point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 50; // shift if the series is longer than 20
                var values = eval(point);
                chart.series[0].addPoint([values[0], values[1]], true, shift);
                chart.series[1].addPoint([values[0], values[2]], true, shift);

                // call it again after defined seconds
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
            },

            success: function (point) {
                var series = chart.series[1],
                shift = series.data.length > 50; // shift if the series is longer than 20

               // add the point
               // chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);
               var values = eval(point);
               chart.series[0].addPoint([values[0], values[1]], true, shift);
               chart.series[1].addPoint([values[0], values[2]], true, shift);
               // call it again after defined seconds
               setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

and here the chart

```
<!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
<script>
```

//is it right here to define chart?

```
var chart; // global
    var region = "<?php Print($region); ?>";
    function requestData() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://cstation.admie.gr/iREACT_cSTATION_WEB/trexousa_katastasi/json.php',
            data: {region:region},  
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",

            error: function (point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],

                    shift = series.data.length > 50; // shift if the series is longer than 20

                    var values = eval(point);
                    chart.series[0].addPoint([values[0], values[1]], true, shift);
                    chart.series[1].addPoint([values[0], values[2]], true, shift);

                    // call it again after defined seconds
                    setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
            },
            success: function (point) {
                var series = chart.series[1],
                    shift = series.data.length > 50; // shift if the series is longer than 20

                // add the point
               // chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);
                var values = eval(point);
                chart.series[0].addPoint([values[0], values[1]], true, shift);
                chart.series[1].addPoint([values[0], values[2]], true, shift);



                // call it again after defined seconds
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
            },
            cache: false
        });



    }

  function InitHighChart()
  {
     $("#chart1").html('LOADING');
     var options = 
     {
        chart: {
           renderTo: 'chart1',
           borderColor: '#a1a1a1',
           borderRadius: 13,
           alignTicks: false,
           zoomType: 'xy',
           height: 700,
           events : {
                load :requestData()
            }
        },

        credits: {
           enabled: false
        },
        title: {
           text: "",
           x: -50
        },

        xAxis: {
           series: [{}],
           labels: {
              rotation: -75
           }
        },

        yAxis: [{ //Primary yAxis
           labels: {
              format: '{value}',
              style: {
                 color: "#000000"
              }
           },
           title: {
              text: '',
              style: {
                 color: "#0B0EED"
              }
           }
        }
        ],

        tooltip: {
           formatter: function() {
              var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';
              $.each(this.points, function(i, point) 
              {
                 s += '<br/>'+point.series.name+': '+point.y;
              });
              return s;
           },
           shared: true
        },
        series: [{},{}]
     };

     //ajax call
     $.ajax({   
        url: "http://...url.../json1.php",
        data: {region:region},   
        type:'post',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
           options.xAxis.categories = data.datetime;
           options.series[0].name = 'Συνολικό Φορτίο (MWatt)';
           options.series[0].data = data.SD_PData;
           options.series[0].color = "#05A43C";

           options.series[1].name = 'Συνολικό Φορτίο Φαινομένου (MVar)';
           options.series[1].data = data.SD_MVAData;
           options.series[1].color = "#EC2E03";

           var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);          
        },
     });
  }
  </script>
```

```
  <!-- 3. Add the container -->
  <div id="chart1" style="width: 1200px; height: 700px; margin: 0 auto"><body onload="InitHighChart()"></div>
```

Comment: how you json does it look like? Morever using eval() function is risky. Better is using JSON.parse();

Comment: i think eval() is ok because updating is OK when i remove the second $ajax which loads past values

Comment: where do you call requestData method? You use chart to add points, but how do you get the chart in the first place? is it stored in a variable which is global to requestData, because you don't do `Highcharts.charts` anywhere in the method. You define `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options)` in your ajax call but that isn't available to requestData method.

Comment: i updated full code...is it right to define there the chart?...i am sure that somthng with those u said i have a problem..thnk u

Comment: Instead of  load :requestData() should be  load :requestData. Also check the errors in the console (dev tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) Let me know about results.

Comment: yes sorry, i ll post console errors..., i used requestData without "()" which is the correct but it doesn't update..thnx Sebastian

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/cb8c9suxd/ console errors it says that highchart already defined in page

Comment: new error is this..fixed last error..Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined..this error inside requestData

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I have done the same thing in one of my code.

```
var options = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart',
    defaultSeriesType: 'column'
},

title: {
    text: 'Voting Results'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: []
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'votes'
    }
},
series: [{}]

};

$.getJSON('votecount2.php', function(data) {
    options.series[0].name = "Votes";
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

My JSON is this

[["Waseem Akhtar",5],["Imran Ismail",4],["Qaim Ali Shah",4]]

Comment: you can reload the specific region so it can update.

Comment: The thing to do is first load data from server an then get live data using 2nd php ...so live data will be updating..i get past data but then graph it doesn't update...do u have an example for this...? but an example not with random data...i need with ajax calls...thank u

Comment: Here is the example provided by [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update)

Comment: yes this is with random data ..i am confusing with 2 ajax calls i make and updating doesn't work.  i load past data but i can't update dynamically with new points..thank u